# Basic scenario of authenticating to an azure registered app using ClientCertificateCredential returns "certificate does not have a private key"

Tags: azure, x509certificate2, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am new to Azure, and am trying a very basic scenario: locally authenticate to a registered app using a certificate credential.

The code is as follows:

```
public async Task<QueueClient> GetQueueClientWithSdkWithCertificateCredentials(string storageAccountName, string queueName, string tenantId, string clientId, string certificateBase64Str)
{
    var certificateCredentials = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certificateBase64Str)));
    var queueClient = new QueueClient(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net/{queueName}"), certificateCredentials);
    var createQueueResponse = await queueClient.CreateAsync();
    if (createQueueResponse.IsError)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error in creating queue: [{createQueueResponse}]");
    }
    return queueClient;
}
```

`queueClient.CreateAsync` is failing with error
`Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: 'ClientCertificateCredential authentication failed: The certificate certificate does not have a private key.`

**My setup is**:

1. I have created myself the certificate - using openssl as follows:
   `.\openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 120 -nodes -subj "/C=XX/ST=MyDistrict/L=MyTown/O=MyCompany/OU=MyOrg/CN=MyCertificate"`
2. I then convert the certificate (cert.pem) to a pfx file so I can properly install it on Windows (checking the "export private key" checkbox so the key icon shows when double clicking on the certificate to see its details).
3. I also make sure it is installed under Trusted Root Certification Authorities, just in case.
4. So certificate is ultimately installed in my windows local store and looks like
   [image]
5. I then upload the cert.pem file to Azure, under my registered app's Certificates & Secrets screen.
6. Then I go to my registered app's Manifests screen, and take the certificate base 64 representation I should be using in the Azure SDK API ("value" prop)
   [image]

**Doing all this** - returns the error mentioned above. What is meant by "The certificate certificate does not have a private key" ? I mean, the certificate installed locally does show the key at the bottom - which indicates it **DOES** have the private key ?

What I am missing ?

Comment: You need to pass certificate as  `var certificatePath = "PFXCertPath";
var certificatePassword = "password"; 
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);`

Comment: I am able to create the queue using certificate based authentication by modifying the [**code**](https://i.imgur.com/WiWhOl8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Created a **Microsoft Entra ID application** and uploaded the certificate:

[image]

Exported the PFX certificate in the local machine:

[image]

The error ***"The  certificate does not have a private key"*** usually occurs if you don't pass the private key.

**To resolve the error,** pass the **private key** and the certificate path when making use of client certificate authentication.

*Modify the code like below to create the Queue using client certificate authentication:*

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string storageAccountName = "testrukstrgacc";
            string queueName = "testrukqueue";
            string tenantId = "TenantID";
            string clientId = "ClientID";
            string certificatePath = "C:/demo/rukcert.pfx";
            string certificatePassword = "Trash33!";

            QueueClient queueClient = await GetQueueClientWithSdkWithCertificateCredentials(storageAccountName, queueName, tenantId, clientId, certificatePath, certificatePassword);

            Console.WriteLine($"Queue client created: {queueClient.Uri}");
        }

        public static async Task<QueueClient> GetQueueClientWithSdkWithCertificateCredentials(string storageAccountName, string queueName, string tenantId, string clientId, string certificatePath, string certificatePassword)
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);

            var certificateCredentials = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);
            var queueClient = new QueueClient(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net/{queueName}"), certificateCredentials);
            var createQueueResponse = await queueClient.CreateAsync();
            if (createQueueResponse.IsError)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Error in creating queue: [{createQueueResponse}]");
            }
            return queueClient;
        }
    }
}
```

***Queue got created successfully:***

[image]

In the Portal:

[image]